# Full Text Index type column is empty

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am trying to create an index on a VarBinary(max) field in my SQL Server 2008 database.

The steps I am taking are as follows:

Table: dbo.Records

- Right click on table and select "Full Text Index"
- Then select "Define Index..."
- I choose the primary key which is the PK of my table (field name Id, type UniqueIndentifier).
- I then get the screen with the options Available Columns, Language for Word Breaker and **Type Column**
- I select my VarBinary(max) field called Chart as the Available Column by ticking the box.
- I select "English" as the Language for Word Breaker field.

Then... I try to select the **Type Column** but there are no entries in here. I cannot proceed by clicking "Next>" until this column is populated.

Why are there no entries in this column for selection and what should be in there?

Note 1: The VarBinary(max) field is linked to a file group if that makes any difference.
Note 2: Also noticed that in the table designer I cannot set the full text option on that same field to "Yes" - its permanently stuck on "No".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The type column is a column in the table that is being indexed.  It should contain the type of data that is in the VarBinary field.  That is doc, XML and so on.  Does that make sense?